# NoSQL strategies for a countries referential

Tags: mongodb, nosql

i'm new in NoSQL and i like how it work but i have some difficulties to think NoSQL. i want to do a place referential with multiple layers : 
 - Country
 - City
 - Place

It is hard to don't think as a relational database. So what is the NoSQL strategy ? My first approach is to create a table named "place" with this format :

```
{
   placename: String,
   placelongitude: Number,
   placelatitude: Number,
   placeparent: String
}
```

But i think this is not the best way for NoSQL. i have think about this way :

```
{
   countryname: String,
   cities: [{
      cityname: String,
      places: [{
         placeid: Number,
         placename: String,
         placelongitude: Number,
         placelatitude: Number
      }],
   }]
}
```

What do you think ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: If `place` has a city and country, why not create docs of `place` ?

Comment: Because join isn't possible in NoSQL if understand correctly?

Comment: $lookup does exist in mongo 3.2

Comment: Ok i haven't see this feature. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store `places` in your collection with `city` and `country` as keys

```
{
    placeid: Number,
    placename: String,
    placelongitude: Number,
    placelatitude: Number,
    cityname: String,
    countryname: String
}
```

Comment: Oh ok, but the repetition is not a problem ? And if i want to add some fields in my city or country like size or other, i will have to repeat this information to ? Or i can put the cityname with city's identifier to get the rest of information if i need to have it ?

Comment: Yea thats a trade off in using a document based DB. Your reads become much faster, but since data is not normalized your update performance isnt great.

Comment: Ok it is clearer thanks, i will try.